# Vuejs combine HTML in label

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this piece of code

```
<vs-option
  v-for="project in projects"
  :key="project.id"
  :label="project.icon + project.name"
  :value="project.id"
/>
```

it's option of select box, `project.icon` value is like `<i class="fas fa-home"></i>` (it's HTML). When I combine it with my `project.name` it turns out like this `<i class="fas fa-home"></i> My Project`

I want my icon html to show as icon but I'm not sure how to combine this two together.

```
:label="project.icon + project.name"
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: is `vs-option` custom component or 3rd party library?

Comment: @NileshPatel it's vuesax UI

Comment: According to the docs, it expects a string and is probably not built to accept an HTML string.

Comment: Example :label="`${project.icon}${name}`", there are ` before $ and before }

Comment: bro :label needs string value and not html value we cannot add html inside label 
so please refer documentation even if we give html as string it wont work because for html there is v-html where it takes html as a string try adding v-html so that you can add your string based html inside it